# SQLite instr(...) case insensitive query

Tags: sqlite, collation, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have a SQL table with case sensitive text.
now I want to search (case insensitive) if words appear in the text. One way of course, is to just do `[...] text LIKE '% <word1> %' AND text LIKE '% <word2> %' ...` but since it's `LIKE '%` it's always a full table scan and I can't use my index. My question: Can that be optimised?

One thing I found was `instr(text, '<word1>') > 0` but that's case sensitive. I also tried it with `COLLATE NOCASE` but nothing changed. Only way here would be to `instr(lower(text), '<word1>')` which again due to the `lower(...)` in not that great (all search words are guarantied lowercase btw).

[Here's](https://tio.run/##fY6xCsIwFEX3fsWjS1Nx0LlTiE9aqAmkD@0mMWQohBZN9PdjKk4Ozufec2@4@ym6lIRGTgjR3LwDAmbhzLVouWb7XQ1C9f2KpRJ8wLopOjmgJugkqU@6hpfxTxeAlbz8z28r/8518oBjtktCSVfCkUBJoLxuF@9NdDAv1gSXG8WAPQqCDRy1OmXppUWNMM0hPpjdQmWq359NSm8) a little example that doesn't work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T (c VARCHAR(10) COLLATE NOCASE);
INSERT INTO T (c) values ("A");
INSERT INTO T (c) values ("b");
CREATE INDEX CONTENT_TEXT ON T(c COLLATE NOCASE);

SELECT * FROM T WHERE instr(c, 'a') COLLATE NOCASE;
```

Comment: Side note: just like `LIKE`, `INSTR()` cannot use an index.

Answer (score 1):

One way to very efficiently search case-insensitively for words in a larger string is to use a [full text search extension](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html).

Example:

```
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test USING fts5(foo);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test(foo) VALUES ('the quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE test MATCH 'FOX';
foo                                             
------------------------------------------------
the quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog
```

If your data already exists in a table, the [external content](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#external_content_and_contentless_tables) mode might be of interest to save some space.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to do anything fancy, just use "lower" function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  Questions
WHERE
  INSTR(lower(Text),lower('Text'))
```

Comment: This "solution" is already in question. And does not answer it.